# How to fetch last row order by date and group by id

Tags: mysql, php, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to skip duplicate `history_id` and take only last update row

```
SELECT products.products_id, products.products_date, products.products_link,
       history_products.history_products_name, history_products.history_products_update, 
       history_products.history_products_stock, history_products.history_products_status

FROM products JOIN history_products
                ON products.products_id=history_products.history_products_id

WHERE products.products_author_id=:products_author_id
   && products.products_store_id=:products_store_id

GROUP BY history_products.history_products_id

ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(history_products.history_products_update, "%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s%p") DESC
```

Comment: tried `DISTINCT` but no luck. `GROUP BY` works but not getting the last row order by date

Comment: You can edit your own question. Also, please format your SQL! This will help make it more readable and get you more good answers!

Comment: Groupwise-max problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm following you correctly, for each row in `products`, you want the most recent matching row in `history_products`. This query should do that:

```
SELECT prod.products_id, prod.products_date, prod.products_link
       history_products.history_products_name, history_products.history_products_update, 
       history_products.history_products_stock, history_products.history_products_status
  FROM history_products
         JOIN (
               SELECT products.products_id, products.products_date, products.products_link,
                      MAX(STR_TO_DATE(history_products.history_products_update, "%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s%p")) as update_date
                 FROM products JOIN history_products
                                 ON products.products_id=history_products.history_products_id
                WHERE products.products_author_id=:products_author_id
                   && products.products_store_id=:products_store_id
                GROUP BY products.products_id, products.products_date, products.products_link
              ) prod ON (    history_products.history_products_id = prod.products_id
                         AND STR_TO_DATE(history_products.history_products_update, "%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s%p") = prod.update_date
                        )
;
```

Here's how it works:

- In the subquery referred to as `prod`, we select the necessary columns from the `products` table, plus the maximum update date for that product.
- Then, we connect back to `history_products` again, this time to pick up the details of the `history_products` row for the current `products_id` value, for the row where the `history_products_update` value matches the most recent update date.
- NOTE: this query does assume that, for any given row in `products`, there will be one and only one `history_products` row with a given `history_products_update` date. If there is more than one history record for a specified date, then additional information would need to be available to determine which `history_products` record was actually the last one.

Since the `ORDER BY` in your original question appeared to have more to do with selecting the proper `history_products` row than with sorting the results, I have not included a sort order for the results. If the results should show the most recently updated product first, through the least recently updated product, you can add the following `ORDER BY` before the closing semi-colon:

```
ORDER BY prod.update_date DESC
```

NOTE: code not tested.

Comment: Its still date `ASC` order not `DESC`

Comment: Do you mean the query is returning the earliest `history_products` row for each product involved, rather than the most recent one?

Comment: yes sir that right

Comment: To do any more for you, I'd need some sample data in the question, along with your expected output. I can say that taking the `MAX` update date for a given product should only return the oldest date if there's only one update date for that product. Just in case you're talking about how the query output is ordered, not the `history_products` rows, I've updated the answer and provided an option `ORDER BY` based on that. I also noted that, if there are more than one `history_products` row with the same `products_id` and `history_products_update`, more info is needed to find the latest one.

Comment: after so many failure i figure out and added `ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(history_products.history_products_update, "%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s%p") DESC` at the end of the query, that all.
thank you so much

Comment: You should get the same results with the `ORDER BY` I mentioned, as that is the results of the `STR_TO_DATE` function, from the subquery.